# Refactoring Ideas for string.replace on multiple properties

Tags: angular, typescript

I am bussy with a app that has a editable script. When I read the script I need to replace some placeholders with local data. This is working but is very sloppy.

```
initScript(script: LegalScript, lead: LeadTl): LegalScript {
    const scriptVar = new LegalScriptVariables(lead);
    script.html1 = this.replaceHtml(script.html1, scriptVar);
    script.html2 = this.replaceHtml(script.html2, scriptVar);
    script.html3 = this.replaceHtml(script.html3, scriptVar);
    script.html4 = this.replaceHtml(script.html4, scriptVar);
    script.html5 = this.replaceHtml(script.html5, scriptVar);
    script.html6 = this.replaceHtml(script.html6, scriptVar);
    script.html7 = this.replaceHtml(script.html7, scriptVar);
    script.html8 = this.replaceHtml(script.html8, scriptVar);
    script.html9 = this.replaceHtml(script.html9, scriptVar);
    script.html10 = this.replaceHtml(script.html10, scriptVar);
    script.html11 = this.replaceHtml(script.html11, scriptVar);
    script.html12 = this.replaceHtml(script.html12, scriptVar);
    script.html13 = this.replaceHtml(script.html13, scriptVar);
    script.html14 = this.replaceHtml(script.html14, scriptVar);
    script.html15 = this.replaceHtml(script.html15, scriptVar);
    script.html16 = this.replaceHtml(script.html16, scriptVar);
    script.html17 = this.replaceHtml(script.html17, scriptVar);
    script.html18 = this.replaceHtml(script.html18, scriptVar);
    script.html19 = this.replaceHtml(script.html19, scriptVar);
    script.html20 = this.replaceHtml(script.html20, scriptVar);
    script.html21 = this.replaceHtml(script.html21, scriptVar);
    script.html22 = this.replaceHtml(script.html22, scriptVar);
    script.html23 = this.replaceHtml(script.html23, scriptVar);
    script.html24 = this.replaceHtml(script.html24, scriptVar);
    script.html25 = this.replaceHtml(script.html25, scriptVar);
    script.html26 = this.replaceHtml(script.html26, scriptVar);
    script.html27 = this.replaceHtml(script.html27, scriptVar);
    script.html28 = this.replaceHtml(script.html28, scriptVar);
    script.html29 = this.replaceHtml(script.html29, scriptVar);
    script.html30 = this.replaceHtml(script.html30, scriptVar);
    return script;   }

  replaceHtml(html: string, scriptVar: LegalScriptVariables) {
    html = this.replaceClientFirstName(html, scriptVar.clientFirstName);
    html = this.replaceClientLastName(html, scriptVar.clientLastName);
    html = this.replaceAgentName(html, scriptVar.agentName);
    html = this.replaceProductName(html, scriptVar.productName);
    html = this.replacePolicyDeductionDate(html, scriptVar.policyDeductionDay);
    html = this.replacePolicyInceptionDate(html, scriptVar.policyInceptionDate);
    return html   }
```

Does anybody have a solution to clean this up a bit?

Comment: what is script here means array or object? can you log a sample `script` here

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like below, inside your `initScript` to apply changes for the fields in the array.

```
const replaceHtml2 = (field, scriptVar) => script[field] = this.replaceHtml(script[field], scriptVar);
[
    'html1',
    'html2'
].forEach(f => replaceHtml2(f, scriptVar));
```